# Die Roll Emulation (Re-rolling the same number looks like nothing happened)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a simple [marbles game](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yJQAAoiuzgjZLsGxt-W-zRf_4RopSLlUbZNru4JZSl0/edit?usp=sharing) for my friends and I to play in Google Sheets.

My script for rolling dice is working well, but when you "roll" the same number as you had before, there's no visual cue that anything happened other than the "script running..." messages at the top of the screen. I'd really like for something noticeable to happen in the merged cells where the die character is, even if that's just clear-pause-new die face. Is there a way to introduce a pause between actions?

Initially, I had the number created by the script visible, and I tried the following methods to create something visual during the script. Now, I've got a nicer looking =CHOOSE formula that calls the Die Face character based on the result of the script.

I've tried:

- Clearing the cell - it happens too fast to see
- Changing the background color and die face several times to simulate a "no-whammy, no-whammy" kind of animation. - also no visual effect
- Introducing Utilities.sleep(200) between color changes - it delayed the entire script running for the correct amount of time, but none of the intermediate steps were visible.
- Browser.msgBox - this works, but is annoying and distracting.

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Put your game on a dialog so that you can animate with Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I have no idea what that means. :-) I will research it, though!

Comment: Take a look at Jquery UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be to use [toast](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg,-title).

A popup window would appear in the lower right corner of the spreadsheet with a custom message and, optionally, a title:

```js
ss.toast("You got a " + math + "!", "The die was cast!");
```

You can also set the amount of time the popup will show up: [toast(msg, title, timeoutSeconds)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg,-title,-timeoutseconds).

Crucially, it doesn't stop users from interacting with the spreadsheet, clicking other buttons and rolling more dices.

#### Reference:

- [toast(msg, title)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg,-title)

Comment: Thank you! I don’t mind the pop up, it was just annoying to have to click “OK”

Comment: @PatrickLollis You're welcome. If this answer was helpful, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.

Comment: @lamblichus Done! This worked like a charm, thank you! I wish I had a way to add a sound to it, but hey..you can't have everything. :-)

Comment: @PatrickLollis I guess you could add audio if you added a sidebar or similar, but yes, it could complicate the issue. You could start looking into [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio).

Comment: @lamblichus well, now you've got me curious, and I've been able to add a dialogue box that opens and closes itself! I know how to use the HTML audio tag, and I found some free dice roll sounds that are perfect, but I'm clueless about where to put my actual audio file so the HTML can play it.

Comment: @PatrickLollis I'd suggest you to post another question if you have problems developing this.

Comment: @lamblichus I appreciate the help so much. I wound up just calling the background and font colors and reversing them with each roll. It looks good. 